# Simulation of an Ethereum network for Research

Tags: ganache, simulation

I am looking into simulating an Ethereum network for a college project and wondering what is the best route to take to get as close to the main nets metrics as possible.

The project involves setting up a number of nodes within a simulated network and simulating the trading of electrical energy between the nodes. I have looked into [Ganache](https://trufflesuite.com/ganache/index.html) but I am unsure if the results (transaction time, block time) will be a realistic representation as the number of trades/nodes in the network increases as it seems block time is configurable to whatever I decide.

Does anyone know of any tools/software which are used commonly for simulating an Ethereum network/performing research experiments with Ethereum?